# How to make SSL work with 1and1 and heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, deployment, hosting, web-deployment

After getting DNS target for both root domain and subdomain, I edited the DNS for the subdomain on 1and1. Heroku confirmed the subdomain is secured. But 1and1 allows only redirect for root domain. There is no place to add DNS target for root domain.

I have set the root domain redirect to https://www... and it goes there fine and shows all secured. But heroku keeps telling me the root domain is not secured. So that's problem one.

The second problem is that when I type www... to go to the site, it goes to www... and not https://www... How can I make it go to https://www...?

EDIT

I have solved the second problem by adding `config.force_ssl = true` on production.rb.

The first problem remains...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DNS service like pointDns ( heroku addon) or TPA like cloudflare.